# Copy sheet to another worksheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to copy the data from one sheet to a sheet in another worksheet.  'sourcerange.copyTo(targetrange)' doesn't work (not same worksheet).

OK - so I tried using setValues().  I got error 'Parameters don't match signature for setValues.' Snippet of my code below.  Help Appreciated.
Many thanks.  Peter
CODE:

```
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("FormResponses");
var workresponsesheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ahDB0n2Y0jMW0K5ewLplF905_KD6P_knsm84P_X_E6I");
var savecurrentweekrange = sheet.getRange("A2:T150");
var savelastweek = workresponsesheet.getSheetByName("lastweek");
var savelastweekrange = savelastweek.getRange("A2:T150");
  
savelastweekrange.setValues(savecurrentweekrange);
```

Comment: From your question, I thought that these threads might be related to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/55564866 https://stackoverflow.com/q/58945505

Comment: Getting the range only gets a range but does not return any values

Answer (score 0):

**Copying from one spreadsheet to another**

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.test2id);//global variables for ssids
  const ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.test1id);
  let ssh = ss1.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let vs = ssh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let tsh = ss2.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  tsh.clearContents();
  tsh.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)
- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)